# How to make the return type of a virtual member function parametric

Tags: c++, polymorphism, subtype

I am implementing a visitor pattern for a syntax tree in C++. Every node in the tree is derived from a base class `Expr` which declares a pure virtual method `accept`. The `accept` method takes a reference to an instance of `Visitor`. Visitor is also an abstract class declaring a `visit` method for every type of node in the syntax tree. So far so good, classic visitor pattern. However, I need to make `accept`'s return type parametric and I haven't figured out how to do it properly yet. Because `accept` is a virtual method I cannot use templates with it like this:

```
class Expr
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    virtual T accept(Visitor<T> &visitor) = 0;
};
```

I can use templates to declare the `Expr` class itself, though:

```
template <typename T>
class Binary;

template <typename T>
class Grouping;

template <typename T>
class Literal;

template <typename T>
class Unary;


template <typename T>
class Visitor
{
public:
    ~Visitor() = default;
    virtual T visitBinaryExpr(Binary<T> &expr) = 0;
    virtual T visitGroupingExpr(Grouping<T> &expr) = 0;
    virtual T visitLiteralExpr(Literal<T> &expr) = 0;
    virtual T visitUnaryExpr(Unary<T> &expr) = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class Expr
{
public:
    virtual T accept(Visitor<T> &visitor) = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class Binary : public Expr<T>
{
    std::shared_ptr<Expr<T>> left_;
    std::shared_ptr<Token> op_;
    std::shared_ptr<Expr<T>> right_;

public:
    Binary(std::shared_ptr<Expr<T>> left, std::shared_ptr<Token> op, std::shared_ptr<Expr<T>> right)
    {
        left_ = left;
        op_ = op;
        right_ = right;
    }

    T accept(Visitor<T> &visitor) override
    {
        return visitor.visitBinaryExpr(*this);
    }

    std::shared_ptr<Expr<T>> getLeft()
    {
        return left_;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<Token> getOp()
    {
        return op_;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<Expr<T>> getRight()
    {
        return right_;
    }
};
```

Because abstract classes cannot be instantiated, the above seems to work. This solution, however, does not feel right (please keep in mind I am a C++ novice). For example, if I have a node of type `Binary` and I want to visit it with two functions that have different return type, I am forced to have an object instance for every return type spacialization and copy the original object back and forth among these to get the appropriate behavior for `accept`.

What would be a better way of implementing the `accept`'s intended behavior?

Comment: As you've noticed, this doesn't work in C++. The crux is the limitations of how dynamic dispatch works. So if you need this, you'll have to eliminate the dynamic dispatch (no virtual functions). Maybe using CRTP or something.

Comment: I have an idea of what an "expression" is here, but what are the visitors? What sort of Visitor would an `Expr` accept? Is it a subexpression?  Can you give a sample visitor?

Comment: Have `accept` return `void`. Store the computed value in the visitor instead, that the caller can retrieve after the visitation is complete. This way, `accept` is agnostic of the computatins the visitor needs to perform.

Comment: You could also take a look at std::any which allows you to return any type

Comment: THe more I think about this, I wonder why you need a visitor at all...

Comment: @mooing "evaluate" is a classic visitor.  Given an AST of math, and values for variables, return a value.  Or one that substitutes literals for values, or calculates a derivative, etc.

Comment: Isn't that something the expression should do? `Expression.evaluate(context)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness, another approach I found to solve this problem is described here: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1018315/Visitor-with-the-Return-Value.
This follows the classic visitor pattern (i.e., have `visit` and `accept` methods return `void`). Different return types are taken care of by a separate template class, and some template magic, as follow:

```
template <typename VisitorImpl, typename ResultType>
class ValueGetter
{
    ResultType value_;

public:
    static ResultType getValue(Expr &e)
    {
        VisitorImpl visitor;
        e.accept(visitor);
        return visitor.value_;
    }

    void returnValue(ResultType value)
    {
        value_ = value;
    }
};

class AstPrint : public Visitor, public ValueGetter<AstPrint, std::string>
{
public:
    void visitBinary(Binary &expr) override
    {
        std::string str;
        str += getValue(expr.getLeft());
        str += expr.getOp()->getLexeme();
        str += getValue(expr.getRight());
        returnValue(str);
    }
 
    /* ... */
};
```

The `AstPrint` class derives from a base templated class `ValueGetter` that contains the derived class itself as template argument, allowing to instantiate a `Visitor` for every node visited by `getValue`. This pattern is called ***Curious Recurrent Template Pattern*** (more information on the pattern can be found here: https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/05/12/curiously-recurring-template-pattern).

`visitBinary` prepares the return data by storing it in the attribute `value_`. Finally, data is returned by `getValue` when `visitBinary` is done visiting the node. A use case for this follows:

```
Expr *expression = new Binary(
        std::make_shared<Unary>(
            std::make_shared<Token>(TokenType::eMINUS, "-", nullptr, 1),
            std::make_shared<Literal>(
                std::make_shared<NumericLiteral>("123")
                )
            ),
        std::make_shared<Token>(TokenType::eSTAR, "*", nullptr, 1),
        std::make_shared<Grouping>(
            std::make_shared<Literal>(
                std::make_shared<NumericLiteral>("45.67")
            )
        )
    );

/* print -123 * (45.67) */
std::cout << AstPrint::getValue(*expression) << std::endl;
```

I think this is what @Igor was suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one way to skin polymorphism.

Inheritance based polymorphism is what you are using to implement the visitor pattern.  I would say ... don't.

From this:

```
virtual T visitBinaryExpr(Binary<T> &expr) = 0;
virtual T visitGroupingExpr(Grouping<T> &expr) = 0;
virtual T visitLiteralExpr(Literal<T> &expr) = 0;
virtual T visitUnaryExpr(Unary<T> &expr) = 0;
```

you already have a closed (or at least enumerated) set of types.

Use `std::variant`.

```
template<class...Ts>
using PolyPtr=std::variant<std::shared_ptr<Ts...>>;
struct Binary;
struct Unary;
struct Literal;
struct Unary;
using ExprPtr=PolyPtr<Binary,Unary,Literal,Unary>;
```

Now you can visit easily

```
struct IsBinary{
  bool operator()(std::shared_ptr<Binary>)const{return true;}
  template<class T.
  bool operator()(std::shared_ptr<T>)const{return false;}
};
ExprPtr p=std::make_shared<Unary>();
std::cout<<std::visit(IsBinary(), p)<<'\n';
```

For this purpose, the types in an expression need not be related.

You can also expose a `virtual std::variant<A*,B*,C*> GetVariant()=0;` method in `Expr` instead, and use that to implement `accept`, if you are addicted to standard polymorphism.

```
template<class V>
auto accept(Expr* expr, V&& v){
  return std::visit([&](auto* ptr){return v(*ptr);}, expr->GetVariant());
}
```

this assumes visitors have an `operator()` with overloads for each type.

Comment: thanks for the helpful answer. I was not aware of *std::variant*. Looks like it provides similar parametric polymorphism as templates with the difference that all possible types have to be spelled out in the declaration of the function rather than substituted as template argument where the function is called (no compiler stamping out function instances for different types in this case). Coming from C programming this reminds me of *union*s. I wonder if *union*s would also work here and if they were the way of solving this type of problems before C++17's *std::variant*.

Comment: @giuse variant is a typesafe union with visit, basically.  Writing parse trees with variant based polymorphism is pretty common today.